# What is meaning of "import weak" in Protocol Buffers Version 2?

Tags: protocol-buffers

[Import Statement](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec#import_statement) in Protocol Buffers Version 2 Language Specification has the following text:

```
import = "import" [ "weak" | “public”] strLit ";"
```

But [Importing Definitions](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing-definitions) in Protocol Buffers Version 2 Language Guide only talks about the use of `public`. What is the meaning of `import weak`? I have googled for an answer. But I fails to find an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weak imports are optional dependencies.

See the documentation for [`EnforceWeakDependencies`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#DescriptorPool.EnforceWeakDependencies.details) for a few details:

> ```
> void DescriptorPool::EnforceWeakDependencies(
>         bool enforce)
> ```
>
> By default, weak imports are allowed to be missing, in which case we will use a placeholder for the dependency and convert the field to be an Empty message field.
>
> If you call EnforceWeakDependencies(true), however, the DescriptorPool will report a import not found error.

Comment: That answers the ``weak`` question. How about the ``public`` question? Or, for that matter, *unspecified*, which I take to mean inferred ``private`` if there was such a thing.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what *"weak imports are optional"* means. Does this mean literally treating the ``label = required | optional | repeated`` as ``optional`` instead of whatever it was in the *.proto*?